# domPDF how to save a file without viewing ? LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

Below is my current code I want to store the pdf inmy files without view it . is it possible ? when user store the data for $bus object on db. I want to store below pdf on my local.

```
 $user = Festivals::where('id', $bus->id)->first();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('user.view', compact('user'));
        $name = 'Ref_no' . $user->ref_no . '_' . date('m-d-Y') . '.pdf';
      return $pdf->download($name);
```

Comment: @Rushikumar I want to store(not viewing , just save file) the file without downloading . its not duplicate of the one u mentioned

Comment: sorry about that; have retracted the flag.

Comment: you can check this link for better solution . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795346/how-to-save-dompdf-file-to-storage-and-name-the-file-dynamicly-in-laravel/74942859#74942859

Answer (score 6):

if `$pdf` is a DomPDF object, use its `output()` method to get pdf content as a string and simply put it in a file;

```
$content = $pdf->output();
file_put_contents('/path/to/your/file', $content);
```

Comment: I've added like this the path file_put_contents(url('/images/pictures') . '/' . $filename, $content);  but im geting http error

Comment: here the error failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Comment: it shouln't be a url, it should be a path, like `/home/images/file.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `Storage::put($filename, $pdf->output())` if you need.