# how to save dompdf file to storage and name the file dynamicly in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, save, dompdf

does anyone know how to save generated pdf file and name it dynamicly using dompdf in laravel?
i always encounter this error

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

while trying to generated pdf file and save it to project directory.
here its my controller code

```
$bills = Tagihan::join('pesanan', 'tagihan.id_pesanan', 'pesanan.id_pesanan')
                    ->join('kendaraan', 'pesanan.id_kendaraan', 'kendaraan.id_kendaraan')
                    ->join('kategori_mobil', 'kendaraan.id_kategori_kendaraan', 'kategori_mobil.id_kategori')
                    ->join('users', 'pesanan.id_pengguna', 'users.id')
                    ->where('pesanan.id_pesanan', $save->id_pesanan)
                    ->select('pesanan.*', 'users.*', 'tagihan.*', 'kendaraan.*', 'kategori_mobil.nama_kategori')
                    ->first();
    $today = Carbon::now('GMT+7')->toDateString();
      $pdf = new PDF();
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.tagihan.pdf', compact('bills','today'));
      file_put_contents('public/bills/'.$noOrder.'.pdf', $pdf->output() );
    return redirect()->route('pesananIndex');
```

i want to save my pdf file with custom string with $noOrder.'pdf', but when i use static name like this

```
file_put_contents('public/bills/bubla.pdf', $pdf->output());
```

i had no error, any solution?

Comment: why file_put_contents?

Answer (score 6):

You can getOriginalContent from http response into a variable then push it to your file.

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.tagihan.pdf', compact('bills','today'));

 $content = $pdf->download()->getOriginalContent();
 Storage::put('public/bills/bubla.pdf',$content);

 ...
```

Comment: In the above example is admin.tagihan.pdf the file already rendered by domPdf?

Comment: @FabricioG  No, no, he must have spelled it wrong or just picked a weird name. There you must put the path of a Blade view (the html code), so much so that the method is called 'loadView'.

Answer (score 5):

```
 Storage::disk('local')->makeDirectory('/pdf/order');
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('PDF.Order.OrderPDF-dev', ['invoiceDetail'=>$invoiceDetail]);


      $path = 'storage/pdf/order/';
      $pdf->save($path  . $fileName);
      return url($path.$fileName);
```

In my example first i created  folder for PDF.  **makeDirectory(...)** will create folder if exist or not.

**$path** is location where i want to put my file in Dir. do not use **absolute path or public path** function here. only define location where you want to create file.

I am creating file in **Storage folder**. so i added **storage/.....**

Answer (score 0):

You can use isset function in your blade.php file like for example  in top the page u can set Id){
$data=$bills} ?>

Now you can open file as a stream